# Disable the swipe in one of ViewPager's tabs

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-viewpager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gesture issue with mapview in viewpager page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117791/gesture-issue-with-mapview-in-viewpager-page)

I use the template that allow us to swipe horizontally between tabs

But one of my tab is **MapView**, so when I swipe left/right in that MapView, it will switch tab instead of moving the map.

Is there any way to disable the gesture only in that MapView tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117791/gesture-issue-with-mapview-in-viewpager-page)

In case the link is dead, I copied the code here:

Make a new class with this exact code, it will prevent MapView to receive any other gesture aside of map-related gesture. Don't forget to add your `package` and `import` (CTRL+SHIFT+O) above these code

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if (v instanceof MapView) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

Then in `main.xml` change the `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ... />` into this:

```
<com.yourPackage.CustomViewPager
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" />
```

Thanks to Jorge Aguilar for the answer in that question!

Comment: plus one for the "In case the link is dead, I copied the code here" line.