# Map freezes, does not allow zooming after being added in sliders tab

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to add map to a tab. I first did this with tabActivity, but since it is deprecated I decided to make it again using sliding tabs and navigation drawer. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) and managed to get it working, but now I have a problem - when I try moving the map with my fingers it becomes very slow, it drags, and moves only a little bit. Another problem I have is with zooming in/out - I can only zoom in when I double tap and cannot zoom out. Also, moving map up and down is disabled.

My map fragment:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MapView mapView;
    Marker marker; // Marker
    int markerCount = 0; // Marker counter

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container,
            false);
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMap = mapView.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_me)));

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        int iMax = 5; // Max number of markers

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

            if (markerCount < iMax) {
                // start SendMessageActivity need to add marker to message activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SendInvitationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                markerCount = markerCount + 1;
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_0))
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                        arg0.longitude))
                        .visible(true));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Only " + iMax + " markers allowed at the same time",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
     });
     return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
      public void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

and xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
         android:id="@+id/mapView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

So my problem is that my map reacts very poorly to finger input. It was not the case when I used TabActivity. I was wondering could this be the sliders problem - since I swipe tabs to move between them, could that "confuse" the map?

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117791/gesture-issue-with-mapview-in-viewpager-page), but it did not work on map, it only disabled swiping between tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I originally added TabLayout and ViewPager below the Toolbar in app_bar_main.xml:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

After I removed the entire AppBarLayout from ***app_bar_main.xml*** and added it in ***content_main.xml*** it works without any glitches.